# NSWindow doesn't receive keyboard events

Tags: macos, nswindow

I am creating an NSWindow from a bundle loaded at runtime so I don't have the source code for the NSWindow that is created at app launch. When I show my window, it receives mouse event but it does not receive any keyboard events. I have tried adding the window with the following methods:

```
[_myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication].mainWindow addChildWindow:_myWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
[NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:_myWindow];
```

In all 3 cases it appears the main window is eating all the keyboard events. The mouse events also leak through to the original window (I can see mouse over highlights and buttons respond to clicks through my window). I have also tried:

```
[_myWindow makeMainWindow];
[_myWindow orderWindow:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:[originalWindow windowNumber]];
```

Any tips to get keyboard events to land on my window would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the window that gets events is the key window, not the main window.

Comment: makeKeyAndOrderFront should make the my window the key window. It still doesn't seem to get events. I am not sure what the original window is doing to grab every event...

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: Any change that there is an event monitor that takes the events before the window? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534971-addlocalmonitorforevents

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass NSApplication and override `sendEvent:` to print `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` before sending the event to the keyWindow (don't forget to call the super to actually send the event).

If the key window does not receive the events, then you might have an [event monitor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534971-addlocalmonitorforevents) somewhere that grabs the events before they are dispatched.